# image gallery with vetical thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, image-gallery, jquery-ui-slider

I installed free jquery slider show, but i want 4 images only inside content.
I tried it, but 2 images appear only . How i can modify this code to show vertical slider show as this plan ...

[slider show plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwVPF.jpg)

[this is wanted slider show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep0cl.jpg)

This is slider code.... please help me .
thanks to all

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Gallery with Vertical Thumbnail Navigater Theme - Jssor Slider, Carousel, Slideshow with Javascript Source Code</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family:Arial, Verdana;background-color:#fff;">
    <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Zoom- in
            {$Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$OutQuad }, $Opacity: 2 },
            //Zoom+ out
            {$Duration: 1000, $Zoom: 11, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 },
            //Rotate Zoom- in
            {$Duration: 1200, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$Swing, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$Swing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} },
            //Rotate Zoom+ out
            {$Duration: 1000, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //Zoom HDouble- in
            {$Duration: 1200, x: 0.5, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 1, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 },
            //Zoom HDouble+ out
            {$Duration: 1200, x: 4, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 11, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear }, $Opacity: 2 },

            //Rotate Zoom- in L
            {$Duration: 1200, x: 0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$Swing, $Zoom: $Jease$.$Swing, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$Swing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} },
            //Rotate Zoom+ out R
            {$Duration: 1000, x: -4, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },
            //Rotate Zoom- in R
            {$Duration: 1200, x: -0.6, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $During: { $Left: [0.2, 0.8], $Zoom: [0.2, 0.8], $Rotate: [0.2, 0.8] }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$Swing, $Zoom: $Jease$.$Swing, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$Swing }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} },
            //Rotate Zoom+ out L
            {$Duration: 1000, x: 4, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} },

            //Rotate HDouble- in
            {$Duration: 1200, x: 0.5, y: 0.3, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} },
            //Rotate HDouble- out
            {$Duration: 1000, x: 0.5, y: 0.3, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 1, $Rotate: 1, $SlideOut: true, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 15 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Top: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InExpo, $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} },
            //Rotate VFork in
            {$Duration: 1200, x: -4, y: 2, $Rows: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Row: 28 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.7} },
            //Rotate HFork in
            {$Duration: 1200, x: 1, y: 2, $Cols: 2, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Assembly: 2049, $ChessMode: { $Column: 19 }, $Easing: { $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Top: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Zoom: $Jease$.$InCubic, $Opacity: $Jease$.$OutQuad, $Rotate: $Jease$.$InCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} }
            ];

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: 1,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $Idle: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $Cols is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 600,                                //Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                },

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable thumbnail navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                    $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                    $Rows: 2,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 14,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 12,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Cols: 6,                             //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                    $Align: 156,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
                    $Orientation: 2                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizing
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 960), 300));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 960px;
        height: 480px; background: #191919; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 240px; top: 0px; width: 720px; height: 480px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/01.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-01.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/02.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-02.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/03.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-03.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/04.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-04.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/05.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-05.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/06.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-06.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/07.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-07.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/08.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-08.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/09.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-09.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/10.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-10.jpg" />
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/11.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-11.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/12.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-12.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/13.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-13.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u="image" src="../img/travel/14.jpg" />
                <img u="thumb" src="../img/travel/thumb-14.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssora05l                  (normal)
            .jssora05r                  (normal)
            .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
            .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                /* size of arrow element */
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                cursor: pointer;
                background: url(../img/a17.png) no-repeat;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
            .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
            .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
            .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
            .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
            .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top: 158px; left: 248px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top: 158px; right: 8px">
        </span>
        <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <!--#region Thumbnail Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-thumbnail-navigator-jquery.html -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 02 css */
            /*
            .jssort02 .p            (normal)
            .jssort02 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
            .jssort02 .p.pav        (active)
            .jssort02 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
            */

            .jssort02 {
                position: absolute;
                /* size of thumbnail navigator container */
                width: 240px;
                height: 480px;
            }

                .jssort02 .p {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 99px;
                    height: 66px;
                }

                .jssort02 .t {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    border: none;
                }

                .jssort02 .w {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                }

                .jssort02 .c {
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 95px;
                    height: 62px;
                    border: #000 2px solid;
                    box-sizing: content-box;
                    background: url(../img/t01.png) -800px -800px no-repeat;
                    _background: none;
                }

                .jssort02 .pav .c {
                    top: 2px;
                    _top: 0px;
                    left: 2px;
                    _left: 0px;
                    width: 95px;
                    height: 62px;
                    border: #000 0px solid;
                    _border: #fff 2px solid;
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                }

                .jssort02 .p:hover .c {
                    top: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 97px;
                    height: 64px;
                    border: #fff 1px solid;
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                }

                .jssort02 .p.pdn .c {
                    background-position: 50% 50%;
                    width: 95px;
                    height: 62px;
                    border: #000 2px solid;
                }

                * html .jssort02 .c, * html .jssort02 .pdn .c, * html .jssort02 .pav .c {
                    /* ie quirks mode adjust */
                    width /**/: 99px;
                    height /**/: 66px;
                }
        </style>

        <!-- thumbnail navigator container -->
        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort02" style="left: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <div u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
                <div u="prototype" class="p">
                    <div class=w><div u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div></div>
                    <div class=c></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!--#endregion Thumbnail Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Image Slider</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a Minimal Working Example? Putting all this code dump would not help anyone.

Comment: I put example as images in this two buttons ( slider show plan ), ( this is wanted slider show ) in my question . my code is complete . you can modify a path of images in code file  only . thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this slider available on below link.

https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.slider

Comment: ok...   let me check , if i can get it for free  from anywhere . .

Comment: well i clicked on Download this slider , and it was downloaded for free.

Comment: I jet it by some modifies , but I fear i think i break Property rights .